# How to retain values in php after submitting or refresh

Tags: php, html

I am working with PHP and whenever I submit the form the values disappear
my code is I want to retain the values

```
<?php
$Name=$Month="";
   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Month=$_POST['Month'];
}
echo $Month;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>abc</title>
   </head>
   <body>
  <form method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Month</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="Month"  required="required" 
   onclick="add_btn('opportunity')">
           <option value=""> Select Type</option>
           <option  <?php if($Month=='January') echo 'selected'? 
 >value="January">January</option>
           <option<?php if($Month=='February') echo 'selected'?> 
          value="February">February</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='March') echo 'selected'?>value="March">March</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='April') echo 'selected'?>value="April">April</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='May') echo 'selected'?> value="May">May</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='June') echo 'selected'?>value="June">June</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='July') echo 'selected'?>value="July">July</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='August') echo 'selected'?>value="August">August</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='September') echo 'selected'? 
     >value="September">September</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='October') echo 'selected'? 
  >value="October">October</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='November') echo 'selected'? 
 >value="November">November</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='December') echo 'selected'? 
>value="December">December</option>
        </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label> Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $Name?>"  name="Name" 
    autocomplete="off" required />
     </div>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

can someone please help me out with this I searched on the net but count find much related to it any help would be appreciated

Comment: All the `<?php if($Month=='XXX') echo 'selected'?>` should do that.

Comment: _Small Point_ outputting things before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` will loose then completely from the browser page

Comment: Unrelated perhaps: may want to look at rendered page - may have spacing issues - e.g. in the April option I'd expect as output (if condition is true) `selectedvalue="April"`.

Comment: Put a space between the `>` and the word `value` in here `>value` The option for `May` looks right but all the other not

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating the answer, your solution works, the only fix is adding space in `?> value="January"` instead of `?>value="January"` in every option.

```
<select class="form-control" name="Month"  required="required" 
   onclick="add_btn('opportunity')">
           <option value=""> Select Type</option>
           <option  <?php if($Month=='January') echo 'selected';?> value="January">January</option>
           <option<?php if($Month=='February') echo 'selected';?>  
          value="February">February</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='March') echo 'selected';?> value="March">March</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='April') echo 'selected';?> value="April">April</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='May') echo 'selected';?> value="May">May</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='June') echo 'selected';?> value="June">June</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='July') echo 'selected';?> value="July">July</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='August') echo 'selected';?> value="August">August</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='September') echo 'selected';?> value="September">September</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='October') echo 'selected';?> value="October">October</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='November') echo 'selected';?> value="November">November</option>
           <option <?php if($Month=='December') echo 'selected';?> value="December">December</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not working  after the submit the field again goes blank